# change position of page number lncs format to print one sided

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, lncs

I am using lncs format for my document... and now I want to print it one sided... But in lncs, the page numbers appear left side for left page and right side for right page... how to change and get all page numbers on the right side header??

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines after `\documentclass{llncs}`

```
\makeatletter
\@twosidefalse
\@mparswitchfalse
\makeatother
```